# Is Q(4th root(2)):Q(sqrt(2)) a Galois extension?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I'm having difficulty with this little exercise. I know it is a Galois extension but I don't know how to prove it formally. Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt[4]{2}$?

Comment: Yes, it is the splitting field of $x^2 - \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you @marlasca23 , I did not notice that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt[4]{2}$ is a root of $x^2 - \sqrt{2} = p(x)\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})/ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is a normal extension as the roots of $p$ are $\pm\sqrt[4]{2}$. As $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})/ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is also separable, it is Galois.

Comment: Thank you! Easy and clear.